# How to use a View Composer variable in the controller

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use the View Composer `$view_name` variable in same controller but it is giving me error.

It is only available to all views, but not for controllers

I want to use that variable in the same controller.

**My controller:**

```
public function boot()
{  
    view()->composer('*', function($view){
        $view_name = str_replace('.', '-', $view->getName());
        view()->share('view_name', $view_name);
    });

    $page_name=substr(strrchr(url()->current(),"/"),1);
    if($page_name==request()->server('HTTP_HOST')) {
        $keywords=keyword::where('page_name','index')->where('active','1')->first();
    } else {
        $keywords=keyword::where('page_name',$page_name)->where('active','1')->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although there are ways to sending variables into a anonymous function and pulling it out, the anonymous function in the composer runs when the view is being rendered. This means you will be using the `$view_name` variable before it has anything assigned. What is it that your trying to do?

Comment: How exactly do you want to re-use `$view_name`? Please show an example or more context.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Middleware to populate a Configuration variable, configuration is always available from all the framework.

```
public function handle()
{
    config(['myCustomConfig.email' => 'me@example.com']);
}
```

**On your controller**

```
$data = config('myCustomConfig.email');
```

**On your view file**

```
<div>{{ config('myCustomConfig.email') }} </div>
```